# Retrieve the number of message from kafka queue via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, apache-kafka

we, dev, have a consumer for a kafka queue (v2.11-0.10.2.1) running on a hadoop environment.

we can retrieve the pending messages from the queue using this command (kafka running locally in each dev computer):

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server server1:port1,server2:port2,server3:port3,server4:port4 --describe --group simple-csharp-consumer
```

but for security's sake, our access has been suspended (the dev team cannot run the command line above anymore). the infra guys said we could try doing the same task using jenkins, so security breach wouldn't be a problem they say.

so, we need help doing the same (retrieving pending kafka messages) via a script running with jenkins.

any help?

Comment: the script to run on jenkins will be hosted on linux

Comment: Edit your question and to explain what is the problem you face.

Comment: @baptistemm what I need is to know **how to configure this task in jenkins**, that is, how call the script kafka-consumer-groups.bat from jenkins

Comment: I'm confused how you are running a `.bat` file between Hadoop or Jenkins. Are both hosted on Windows servers? Your first comment says it's hosted on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the connection is already established between jenkins and hadoop servers by your infra team,

- Create a **new item**
- In the build section, select '**Execute shell'.**
- Enter this:

  ssh applicationID@serverName 'kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server server1:port1,server2:p'
- Click **Save**. Then **Build Now**.

It will do.